# What does TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting mean in python

Tags: python, macos, terminal

here is my first program it basically says stuff out loud and in different voices :

```
import os
print "Hello, Welcome to the speaking program"
speak = raw_input("What would you like to say?\n")
type = raw_input("Would you like\n1. Normal Voice\n2. High Pitched\n3. Low Pitched?\n4. Whisper\n5. Indian Voice\n Please choose 1,2,3,4 or 5\n")

if type == "1":
    os.system("say %s " % speak)
if type == "2":
   os.system("say -v good %s" % speak)
if type == "3":
    os.system("say -v bad %s" % speak)
if type == "4":
    os.system("say -v whisper %s" % speak)
if type == "5":
    os.system("say -v sangeeta $s" % speak)
if type < "5":
    os.system("echo that is not an option")

finish = raw_input("I have done the job, Pick an option\n1. Quit\n2. New Word\n3. Change Pitch\n")

if finish == "1":
    quit()
if finish == "2": 
    os.system("clear")
    os.system("python speak.py")
if finish == "3": 
    type2 = raw_input("Would you like\n1. Normal Voice\n2. High Pitched\n3. Low Pitched\nor\n4. Whisper voice?\n5.Indian Voice\n")    
    if type2 == "1":
        os.system("say %s " % speak)
    if type2 == "2":
        os.system("say -v good %s" % speak)
    if type2 == "3":
        os.system("say -v bad %s" % speak)
    if type == "4":
        os.system("say -v whisper %s" % speak)
    if type == "5":
        os.system("say -v Sangeeta %s" % speak)

    else:
        print "That is not an option"
        os.system("clear")
        os.system("python speak.py")

else:
    print "That is not an option !!! "
    os.system("clear")
    os.system("python speak.py")

finish = raw_input("I have done the job, Pick an option\n1. Quit\n2. New Word\n3. Change Pitch\n")
if finish == "1":
    os.system("logout")
    os.system("killall Terminal")
if finish == "2": 
    os.system("clear")
    os.system("python speak.py")
if finish == "3": 
    type3 = raw_input("Would you like \n1. Normal Voice\n2. High Pitched\n3. Low Pitched?\n4. Whisper voice\n5.Indian Voice\n")    
    if type3 == "1":
        os.system("say %s " % speak)
    if type3 == "2":
        os.system("say -v good %s" % speak)
    if type3 == "3":
        os.system("say -v bad %s" % speak)
    if type3 == "4":
        os.system("say -v whisper %s" % speak)
    if type3 == "5":
        os.system("say -v Sangeeta %s" % speak)
    else:
        print "That is not an option"
        os.system("clear")
        os.system("python speak.py")
```

and this is the error:

```
Shameers-MacBook-Pro:Test Programs Shameer$ !!
python speak.py 
Hello, Welcome to the speaking program
What would you like to say?
hello
Would you like
1. Normal Voice
2. High Pitched
3. Low Pitched?
4. Whisper
5. Indian Voice
 Please choose 1,2,3,4 or 5
5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "speak.py", line 16, in <module>
    os.system("say -v sangeeta $s" % speak)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Please help me. I am young and need some help. Will only down vote if you aren't trying to answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You put a dollar sign instead of a percent sign:

```
os.system("say -v sangeeta $s" % speak)
```

This should be:

```
os.system("say -v sangeeta %s" % speak)
```